# Why HTTP OPTIONS request doesn't work on PHP-FPM?

Tags: php, apache, fastcgi

When using apache handler instead of FastCGI / PHP-FPM I can use a workaround to response a preflight HTTP request, checking REQUEST_METHOD and returning http code 200.

However using FastCGI handler the same code doesn't work, and chrome fails saying Access-Control-Allow-Origin was found on request.

Is there a way to make this work?

```
    $http_origin = $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'];
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: $http_origin");  
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Origin, Authorization");
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "OPTIONS"){
        exit(0);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Removing:**

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS');
```

**Rearranging to:**

```
$http_origin = $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'];

header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Origin, Authorization, X-Auth-Token");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: $http_origin");

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === "OPTIONS"){
    exit(0);
}
```

Worked fine. I had to change the mpm module since I had the issue and today I needed to change.